# How to activate Bootstrap popover for new jQuery element?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Does anyone know how to activate Bootstrap popover on newly created element or in that matter any jQuery events on new elements?

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7NB/1/

```
$('#example').popover({
    trigger: 'hover'
});




var newel = $('<a/>', {
    class: 'btn btn-primary',
        'data-content': 'New popover element',
        'data-original-title': 'New popover',
    text: 'New popover'
}).appendTo('body');
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the .popuper({ trigger: 'hover' }) call to the newly created element should fix the problem:

```
var newel = $('<a/>', {
    'class': 'btn btn-primary',
    'data-content': 'New popover element',
    'data-original-title': 'New popover',
    'text': 'New popover'
}).appendTo('body').popover({ trigger: 'hover' });
```

Comment: beat me to the punch. Here's a fiddle to show some dynamic popover action: http://jsfiddle.net/RRGnb/

Comment: Hehe. Benn, glad to help. Please mark your question as answered :-).

Comment: trying :) must wait few min